# Why are map icons missing?

Tags: dead-space-remake

I've noticed that sometimes the map isn't displaying any icons, and it makes using the map much harder:

[image: Screenshot with missing map icons]

In the above screenshot, we can see a map of the bridge, and we should at least see icons for the save station, elevators, bench, and shop, but they are not displayed.

Why is that, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has something to do with the zoom distance.

I'm not sure why the game sometimes changes the map's zoom distance. Maybe it's automatically setting the zoom level to display the full map at once. However, zooming into the map will make the icons appear, while zooming out will make them disappear again.

Note that the distance to the camera also matters and that each icon is affected individually. As a result, depending on your camera's rotation, it's possible for the map to only display some of the icons and not all of them.